# How to take derivative of integral of function?

Tags: calculus-of-variations, lagrange-multiplier, variational-analysis

I'm reading a textbook where it forms a Lagrangian function

$$ L = \int_0^1 f(x)^{1 - \frac{1}{\alpha}}dx - \lambda\int_0^1 g(x) f(x) dx$$
But how do you take the derivative of this thing? The variable that we want to optimize is $f(x)$, which is a function ($g(x)$ is a known function). So we need to take the derivative with respect to a function? How?

So in this case, what are the first-order conditions?

Comment: If you are seeking to "optimize" the functional $L[f]$, then use the [Calculus of Variations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculus_of_variations).

Answer (score 3):

An important result of the [calculus of variations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculus_of_variations) is that if you have a *functional* $L[f(x)]$ such that
$$
L[f] =\int_a^b J(x,f,f') dx,
$$
$L$ is minimized if
$$
\frac{\partial J}{\partial f} - \frac{d}{dx} \frac{\partial J}{\partial L'} = 0.
$$
This is the [Euler-Lagrange equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation). In your case,
$$
L[f] = \int_0^1 \left[f(x)^{1-1/\alpha}-\lambda g(x) f(x) \right] dx,
$$
therefore the Euler-Lagrange equation leads to
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial f} \left[f(x)^{1-1/\alpha}-\lambda g(x) f(x) \right]  - \frac{d}{dx} \frac{\partial}{\partial f'} \left[f(x)^{1-1/\alpha}-\lambda g(x) f(x) \right]  =0.
$$
The derivative in relation to $f'$ vanishes because $L[f]$ does not depend on $f'$. Evaluating the derivative in relation to $f$:
$$
\frac{\alpha-1}{\alpha}f(x) ^{-1/\alpha} - \lambda g(x) = 0
$$
and now solving for $f$:
$$
 f(x) = \left( \frac{\lambda \alpha}{\alpha-1} g(x)\right)^{-\alpha},
$$
which is the $f(x)$ that minimize your $L$.